# Getting a line of string and converting into a float list

Tags: c++, string

I need to achieve the following:

```
"4 5 1.3 0 3.1"
```

This is the input string that I will read from the user, after reading I need to turn this string into a float list according to the `[0]`th character's size for example the list will be

```
array[4] = [5.0,1,3,0.0,3.1]
```

How can I achieve it I tried using `getline` but didnt work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried stringstream and new?

Comment: yeah but the 0th index makes it kinda not applicable because  I think you need a loop for stringstream.

Comment: Show us what you did.

Comment: stringstream ss(str_line);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  ss >> data[i];
}

Comment: but the thing is 0th index includes the size of the array

Comment: please [edit] the question to add the relevant parts to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string line = "4 5 1.3 0 3.1"; // input string
istringstream stream(line); // parser
unsigned count; // how many values
double* values;
if (stream >> count) {
    values = new double[count];
    for (unsigned ii = 0; ii < count; ++ii) {
        stream >> values[ii]; // read one
        if (!stream) {
            throw std::runtime_error("not enough numbers");
        }
    }
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error("no count at start of line");
}

// do something with values...

delete[] values;
```

Comment: thank you. is there any way doing this without vectors ?

Comment: @BallsyCoder: Sure, I changed it to use `new[]` and `delete[]` instead of vector.  This isn't very good practice (at a minimum you should use a smart pointer to avoid explicit delete), but for exercise/teaching it will work.

Answer (score 0):

First read the count into an unsigned integer, then loop from 0 to the count, reading into doubles. To read into an array, first allocate one dynamically with the correct size. Better, use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which will handle the allocations for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::istringstream ss(line);

    size_t  num_values = 0;
    if (! (ss >> num_values) ) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read the integer number of values!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    auto values = std::make_unique<double[]>(num_values);
    double tmp;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < num_values; ++idx) {
        if (! (ss >> values[idx])) {
            std::cerr << "Could not convert the " << idx << "th value!\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Validate solution: print the contents of the vector
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < num_values; ++idx) {
        std::cout << values[idx] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2591e1eade857ed)]

This solution uses a dynamically allocated array, and ensures that its memory is correctly cleaned up by wrapping it in a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), created via a call to [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).